# Shared mapping for derived types in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got a class hierarchy that I've flattened out in some models, and I wish to use some common mapping when doing the reverse mapping from the models.

Note: This is a sample and it's been simplified. `typeof(MyDerived)` does not exist in the real code, a type mapping has been removed from this sample.

My configuration is as follows:

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyBase>()
    //.Include<MyModel, MyDerived>() // (1)
    .ForMember(x => x.Children, opts => opts.MapFrom<ChildResolver>())
    .ConstructUsing((model, ctx) => (MyBase)ctx.Mapper.Map(model, model.GetType(), typeof(MyDerived)));
cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyDerived>();
    //.IncludeBase<MyModel,MyBase>(); // (2)
cfg.CreateMap<ChildModel, MyChild>()
    .ConstructUsing((model, ctx) => (MyChild)ctx.Mapper.Map(model, model.GetType(), typeof(MyDerivedChild)));
cfg.CreateMap<ChildModel, MyDerivedChild>();
```

I'm trying to use the mapping configuration both for mapping to new objects and existing objects. `Map<T>` and `Map()`.

When executing the following code the mapping for `Children` is executed twice depending on the commented configuration.

When having `.Include<MyModel, MyDerived>()` in the `MyBase` configuration, creating a new object results in mapping performed twice. Mapping to existing `MyDerived` object maps once.

When having `.IncludeBase<MyModel,MyBase>()` in the derived configuration, mapping to existing objects results in mapping performed twice. Mapping to existing `MyDerived` object maps once.

Moving mapping `.ForMember(x => x.Children, opts => opts.MapFrom<ChildResolver>())` to descendant configuration(s) solves the problem, but then mapping is duplicated.

This makes absolute sense, and the problem is solved by having no other configuration for the `MyBase` configuration except the `ConstructUsing`. However, that means replicating the mapping for every descendant.

So, how can this be configured correctly to allow for centralized mapping configuration?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: Yes, that’s nice and I’m familiar with mapping inheritance but it’s really the ConstructUsing that’s causing the behaviour I’m experiencing here, and I’m asking for an alternative for sharing mapping between descendants.

Comment: Yes, the `ConstructUsing` is the problem. Get rid of it :) You're misusing mapping inheritance.